# How to cast/convert an unsigned char array to a const unsigned char array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, char, constants

I know that this is a silly question. How do you convert an unsigned char array (with values) to a const unsigned char array?

Below is the code that I have tried. It does not make sense, but a const char does not allow you to change the values (as meant by the word const) but I need a const unsigned char array to pass to a function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t a[] = {0, 10, 0, 0, 35, 45, 99, 100,88,67,34,23,56};
    unsigned char k[13];
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(k)/sizeof(unsigned char); i++)
    {
        k[i] = a[i];
        printf("%X\t%d\n",k[i],k[i]);
    }

    // k = (const)k[]; -- cannot cast char array to const char array 

    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what can be done, thanks. Below is the function declaration that k (const unsigned char *k) is to be passed.

```
int crypto_aead_encrypt(
    unsigned char *c, unsigned long long *clen,
    const unsigned char *m, unsigned long long mlen,
    const unsigned char *ad, unsigned long long adlen,
    const unsigned char *nsec,
    const unsigned char *npub,
    const unsigned char *k
)
```

Comment: You can't convert non-const to const.

Comment: Edit the question to show the function declaration. A function that is said to take a “const unsigned char array” as an argument probably actually has a parameter whose type is `const unsigned char *`, a pointer to a `const unsigned char`. To pass your array `a` to it, you merely use `a` as an argument. An array argument will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, yielding an `unsigned char *`, and, for a properly declared function, that will be automatically converted to a `const unsigned char *`.

Comment: As suspected, the parameter is `const unsigned char *`, not an array. So simply pass `a`. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @Barmar, you can absolutely cast a non-const to a const in C

Comment: @Elzaidir But you can't assign to an array, so you can't convert the array`k` from non-const to const.

Comment: zahid kamil, Post the code that shows the call to `crypto_aead_encrypt()`.

Comment: zahid kamil, "I need a const unsigned char array to pass to a function." is incorrect.

Comment: Actually @EricPostpischil you were right. It worked by simply passing in an unsigned char * to the function that requires a const unsigned char * as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`const` here is a qualifier meaning "this function will not alter this variable". It's a guarantee about the function's behavior, not about what you're passing in. It's ok to pass a non-const variable to a function taking a const.

For example, the following is fine. It's ok to pass a `char *` to `const char *`. `main` is allowed to alter the string, but `foo` is not.

```
void foo(const char *a) {
    puts(a);
}

int main()
{
    char *str = strdup("testing");
    foo(str);
}
```

However, the following is an error. It doesn't matter that `str` was not declared with `const`, `foo` promised not to modify its argument.

```
void foo(const char *a) {
    // error: assignment of read-only location '*a'
    a[0] = 'r';
    puts(a);
}

int main()
{
    char *str = strdup("testing");
    foo(str);
}
```

---

You should not go the other way. Passing a const to a non-const function  is undefined. It might work, it might not.

```
// note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *
void foo(char *a) {
    a[0] = 'r';
    puts(a);
}

int main()
{
    const char str[] = "testing";

    // warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    foo(str);
}
```